# Functional programing function

Tags: functional-programming

How to write a functional program for the union of two lists or sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the language, but generally, there'll be a recursive solution involving traversal of the sets identifying shared elements.

E.g. in Haskell on the native `Data.Set` type,

```
union :: Ord a => Set a -> Set a -> Set a
union Tip t2  = t2
union t1 Tip  = t1
union t1 t2 = hedgeUnion (const LT) (const GT) t1 t2

hedgeUnion _     _     t1 Tip
  = t1
hedgeUnion cmplo cmphi Tip (Bin _ x l r)
  = join x (filterGt cmplo l) (filterLt cmphi r)
hedgeUnion cmplo cmphi (Bin _ x l r) t2
  = join x (hedgeUnion cmplo cmpx l (trim cmplo cmpx t2))
           (hedgeUnion cmpx cmphi r (trim cmpx cmphi t2))
  where
    cmpx y  = compare x y
```

Or more simply, for lists:

```
unionBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionBy eq xs ys        =  xs ++ foldl (flip (deleteBy eq)) (nubBy eq ys) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question, but I'll bite. In Python:

```
lambda x, y: x + filter(lambda z: z not in x, y)
```

Comment: I wouldn't say so, but you can write functional code in it. :)

Comment: Agreed. It's not purely functional in the sense of Haskell or F#, but it has some support for the functional paradigm.